# C++17 view over the Ith elements of tuples in containers of tuples

Tags: c++, c++17, template-meta-programming

For mainly didactic reasons, I have designed my `ElementsView<I, T>` class template, which provides a view over the `I` th elements of each tuple contained by a given container `T`, provided that container supports `operator[]`.  The entry point is the factory function template `animal::util::elements<I>(...sequence-container-of-tuples...)`.

This is similar (though way less powerful) to C++20's `std::ranges::elements_view`, and is designed to interop with a custom "zip" view (not shown, maybe in some other review).

I'm looking for any kind of insight/criticism, but my main doubt is about this `lref_iff_lref_t` helper I "invented" to the `elements` functions accept rvalues.  That is, so I can write things like:

```cpp
elements<1>(elements<2>(container_of_tuples_of_tuples));
```

I'm also looking for simplification, hidden performance problems and UB.

So here is the code, follow by "Catch2" tests

```cpp
// eview.hpp
#include <tuple>

#ifdef EVIEW_MP_TESTS
#include <type_traits>
#include <vector>
#endif

namespace animal::util::eview {
  using std::size_t, std::remove_reference_t, std::decay_t,
    std::tuple_element_t, std::is_same_v;

  /**
   * fwd_tup_elem_t<I, TUP>
   *
   * Get Ith type of tuple TUP, cvref'ed as TUP */
  template <size_t I, typename Tup>
  struct fwd_tup_elem;

  template <size_t I, typename Tup>
  using fwd_tup_elem_t = typename fwd_tup_elem<I, Tup>::type;

  template <size_t I, typename T>
  struct fwd_tup_elem<I, const T> {using type = const fwd_tup_elem_t<I, T>;};

  template <size_t I, typename T>
  struct fwd_tup_elem<I, T&> {
    using type = tuple_element_t<I, remove_reference_t<T>> &;
  };

  template <size_t I, typename T>
  struct fwd_tup_elem<I, T&&> {
    using type = tuple_element_t<I, remove_reference_t<T>> &;
  };

  /**
   * fwd_cont_val<TC>
   *
   * Get value_type of tuple container TC, cvref'ed as TC */
  template <size_t I, typename TC>
  struct fwd_cont_val;

  template <size_t I, typename TC>
  using fwd_cont_val_t = typename fwd_cont_val<I, TC>::type;

  template <size_t I, typename TC>
  struct fwd_cont_val<I, const TC&> {
    using type = const fwd_tup_elem_t<I, const typename TC::value_type&>;
  };

  template <size_t I, typename TC>
  struct fwd_cont_val<I, TC&> {
    using type = fwd_tup_elem_t<I, typename TC::value_type&>;
  };

  template <size_t I, typename TC>
  struct fwd_cont_val<I, TC&&> {
    using type = fwd_tup_elem_t<I, typename TC::value_type&>;
  };

  #ifdef EVIEW_MP_TESTS
  // ERROR, GOOD: non-supported tuple type
  // static_assert(is_same_v<tup_fwd_t<0, std::tuple<int>>, int>);
  static_assert(is_same_v<tup_fwd_t<0, std::tuple<int>&>, int&>);
  static_assert(is_same_v<tup_fwd_t<0, const std::tuple<int>&>, const int&>);
  static_assert(is_same_v<tup_fwd_t<0, const std::tuple<int>&&>, const int&>);

  // ERROR, GOOD: non-supported vector type
  // static_assert(is_same_v<val_fwd_t<0, std::vector<std::tuple<int>>>, int>);
  static_assert(is_same_v<val_fwd_t<0, std::vector<std::tuple<int>>&>, int&>);
  static_assert(is_same_v<val_fwd_t<0, std::vector<std::tuple<int>>&&>, int&>);
  static_assert(is_same_v<val_fwd_t<0, const std::vector<std::tuple<int>>&>, const int&>);
  #endif

  /**
   * lref_iff_lref_t<TC>
   *
   * TC& if TC is T&.  TC if TC is T&&.  Error otherwise */
  template <typename T>
  struct lref_iff_lref;

  template <typename T>
  using lref_iff_lref_t = typename lref_iff_lref<T>::type;

  template <typename T>
  struct lref_iff_lref<T&> {using type = T&;};

  template <typename T>
  struct lref_iff_lref<T&&> {using type = remove_reference_t<T>;};

  /**
   * ElementsView<I, TC>
   *
   * View over Ith elements of each tuple contained by container TC.
   *
   * C++17.  Only operator[] and size() supported.  Kind of like
   * std::ranges::elements_view (C++20), but works with custom "zip"
   * pseudo-container (not shown) as std::ranges::zip_view not available 
   * until C++23.  */
  template <size_t I, typename TC>
    class ElementsView {
    static constexpr size_t index = I;

  public:
    using value_type = fwd_cont_val_t<I, TC>;

    explicit ElementsView(TC c) : data_{c}  {}

    value_type& operator[](size_t pos) { return std::get<index>(data_[pos]);}
    value_type& operator[](size_t pos) const { return std::get<index>(data_[pos]);}
    auto size() const { return data_.size();}
  private:
    lref_iff_lref_t<TC> data_;
  };

  template<size_t I, class U>
  auto elements(U&& u) { return ElementsView<I, decltype(u)>{std::forward<U>(u)};}

}  // namespace animal::util::eview

namespace animal::util { using eview::elements; }

// eview-tests.hpp

#include "catch2/catch_test_macros.hpp"
#include <array>

namespace util = animal::util;

TEST_CASE("basic util::elements") {
  std::array<std::pair<int, char>, 3> ap{{{1, 'a'}, {2, 'b'}, {3, 'c'}}};

  auto ev1 = util::elements<1>(ap);
  ev1[1] = 'z';

  auto ev0 = util::elements<0>(ap);
  ev0[1] = 42;

  const auto& cap = ap;
  REQUIRE(cap[1].first == 42);
  REQUIRE(cap[1].second == 'z');

  auto cev0 = util::elements<0>(cap);
  // TD<decltype(cev0)::value_type> mistery;
  // ev3[2] = 26; // ERROR, GOOD: cap is const, so ev3 has const value_type
  auto cev1 = util::elements<1>(cap);
  REQUIRE(cev0[1] == 42);
  REQUIRE(cev1[1] == 'z');
}

TEST_CASE("more util::elements") {
  using TOP = std::tuple<std::pair<int, std::pair<int, int>>, char, std::string>;
  std::vector<TOP> vtop { {{1, {11, 111}}, 'A', "a"}, {{2, {22, 222}}, 'B', "b"} };

  auto ev0 = util::elements<0>(vtop);
  REQUIRE(ev0[1].first == 2);

  util::elements<0>(vtop)[1].first = 3;

  REQUIRE(util::elements<0>(vtop)[1].first == 3);
  REQUIRE(std::get<0>(vtop[1]).first == 3);

  auto composed{util::elements<0>(util::elements<0>(vtop))};
  REQUIRE(composed[1] == 3);
  composed[1] = 4;
  REQUIRE(util::elements<0>(vtop)[1].first == 4);
  REQUIRE(std::get<0>(vtop[1]).first == 4);

  const auto& cvtop = vtop;
  auto intermediate = util::elements<0>(cvtop);
  auto composed2{util::elements<0>(util::elements<0>(cvtop))};
  REQUIRE(composed2[1] == 4);
  // composed2[1] = 777; // ERROR, GOOD: source owning container is const

  auto composed3{util::elements<1>(util::elements<1>(util::elements<0>(cvtop)))};
  REQUIRE(composed3[1] == 222);
  // composed3[1] = 777;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! I have rolled back Rev 2 → 1. Please see [_What to do when someone answers_](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: Alright.  I'll post that as a self-answer.  Seems acceptable according to the guidelines.  Do tell if it's not.

Comment: Like [that linked page](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) mentions it is fine as long as you "_Describe what you changed, and why [Code-only answers that don't actually review the code are insufficient](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1463/120114) and are subject to deletion._"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Missing iterators

As it is now, I would say it is cute, but not very useful. In most of your test code, you can see that using `std::get<>()` requires less typing than using `util::elements<>()`. However, your class would really shine if it implemented iterators, such that you can do:

```
for (auto& e0: util::elements<0>(vtop)) {
    std::cout << e0.first << '\n';
}
```

But also so that you can use many of the STL algorithms on your view.

## There is no need for the helper templates

You can make your code deduce the right type for `data_` without needing `lref_iff_lref_t`. In:

```
template<size_t I, class U>
auto elements(U&& u) {
    return ElementsView<I, decltype(u)>{std::forward<U>(u)};
}
```

If `u` is an lvalue-reference, `U` is deduced as `U&`. However, if `u` is an rvalue-reference, `U` is deduced as `U`. However, `decltype(u)` will deduce the rvalue-reference that you don't want. The solution is to simply remove the `decltype()` here:

```
return ElementsView<I, U>{std::forward<U>(u)};
```

There will be some compile errors then due to the `fwd_*` templates deducing the wrong thing. However, a much simpler solution is to let the compiler deduce the type for you from the `std::get<>()` expression you are using:

```
using value_type = decltype(std::get<index>(data_[0]));
```

However, both your original `value_type` and the one using `decltype()` have an issue:

## What about `const` views?

There is a problem when making a `const` view.The `const`-qualified `operator[]` will still return a mutable reference to `data_`, if the latter is an lvalue reference to a non-`const` container. Slapping a `const` in front of it [doesn't work though](https://www.fluentcpp.com/2018/07/13/the-incredible-const-reference-that-isnt-const/), because that will make it a `const` reference instead of a reference to `const` data. You have to remove the reference from `value_type` first, then add the `const &` back to it:

```
const std::remove_reference_t<value_type>& operator[](size_t pos) const {
    return std::get<index>(data_[pos]);
}
```

Or better, don't let `value_type` lie, and make sure it is a value type and not a reference to begin with:

```
using value_type = std::remove_reference_t<...>;
```

Note that you could also have avoided the issue by using `auto` return type deduction:

```
const auto& operator[](size_t pos) const {
    return std::get<index>(data_[pos]);
}
```

Comment: Fantastic. You shaved off 70% of the cruft and found a const bug with an elegant solution. Most importantly I understood everything.  As to iterators, maybe. I'm using this with a "zip" view wrapper which provides them (and where std algorithms work ofc) Maybe I'll post that soon, and looking forward to your 70% cut there.  ;-)